# Regex for finding the inverse of a queried string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to isolate all the usernames from a server log.

How can I find the inverse of regex query for a string?

I have

```
/(?<=username=)(.*)(?=&password)/g
```

and that will find me *tom* and *jerry* from the following

> "POST /v1/login HTTP/1.1" 403 24 "-" "curl/7.47.0" "-"
>   "username=tom&password=tom1q2w" "POST /v1/login HTTP/1.1" 403 24 "-"
>   "curl/7.47.0" "-" "username=jerry&password=jerryqawsed"

But then I want to replace the inverse string with \n, so I'll have a column of usernames.

Comment: Try [`.*?username=(.*?)&password.*`](https://regex101.com/r/oKljPC/1) and replace with `$1\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
.*?username=(.*?)&password.*
```

and replace with `$1\n`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oKljPC/1)

**Details**:

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first...
- `username=`  - literal char sequence
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1 matching any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first...
- `&password` -  literal char sequence
- `.*`  - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

The `$1` is a replacement backreference inserting the value inside Group 1 back into the resulting string.